# Long screw that wont come out

Tags: ceiling-fan, screws

I am trying to get a long screw out of the box for a ceiling fan. The head is not stripped and the screw only comes out a little and then hits a point where it stops. I have tried screwing it back in and then out, but still no luck. This particular screw is attached to the fan box in the wall and to the attachment that holds the extension pole of the fan. Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: A photo might be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a bolt with a nut, and now that it's loosened the nut and bolt spin together? If so, try applying downward force to the bolt as you turn it. So that the nut gets held in place as the bolt spins free.

Comment: It might be easier to cut off the head (assuming this releases the unit), disassemble the unit, and replace the screw. This assumes you cannot access the other end of the screw. Also, have you tried grabbing it with the vice grips and yanking down?

Answer (score 3):

Try (this may well be awkward, and will probably need a pair of locking pliers rather than a screwdriver - assuming it unscrewed far enough to get those on before it stopped) pulling down on the screw as you unscrew it. Whatever it's screwed into (a plate, or a nut) is now turning with it - you are trying to get the plate or nut to jam so that you can continue to unscrew it.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Hopefully it works. I will let you know

Comment: no luck with the locking pliers